# How to calculate the amount of battery power used by a particular application in Meego OS?

Tags: power-management, meego

i'm trying to calculate how much battery power is used by a particular application when i run it on mobile (Nokia N900, Meego OS). i don't know how to do that. how can i calculate accurately?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Install Energy Profiler - should be part of the SDK for Nokia N9. I bet there is also one for the N900, but not seen it.